# StartActivityforResult crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Let's say that I have 3 activities, First is MainActivity, Second is PopUp, Third is SearchCategory.

What I am trying to do is that I will start this activity, PopUp which has a button. Now when I click this button I want it to store it as a string and pass it as an Intent so I can use it for the MainActivity to compare it for something.

This worked for my SearchCategory class.

The problem that I am getting is that it crashes when I click the button in the PopUp class.

The codes for my MainActivity's onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle searchCategory = data.getExtras();
            if (start.equals("1")){
                route = searchCategory.getString("route");
            }else {
                start = searchCategory.getString("start");
                route = searchCategory.getString("route");
            }
            ...
        }
```

The codes of the button of my SearchCategory class:

```
public void search(View view) {

        category = (MaterialBetterSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
        category_string = category.getText().toString();

        route = (MaterialBetterSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_routes);
        route_string = route.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("start", category_string);
        bundle.putString("route", route_string);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();

    }
```

The codes of my PopUp class:

```
package rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

/**
 * Created by Julian on 8/5/2017.
 */

public class PopUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    String route, start = "1";
    TextView textView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.pop_layout);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.5));
        route = getIntent().getExtras().getString("route");

        //Checks if I retrieved the intent correctly
        if (route.equals("Sample Route")){
            textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView2.setText("Nice");
        }
    }

    public void getRoute(View view) {
        if (route.equals("Sample Route")){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("start", start);
            intent.putExtra("route", route);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

This is error that I am getting after clicking the button:

```
08-18 00:08:47.221 2807-2813/? E/jdwp: Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
08-18 00:08:50.341 2807-2807/rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
08-18 00:08:50.821 2807-2807/rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method jx.b
08-18 00:08:58.441 2807-2807/rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion, PID: 2807
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion/rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:131)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: Now both crashes. The SearchCategory was working fine before! :(

Comment: What is line 131 in MainActivity? Is it the `if (start.equals("1"))` line? If that is the case, where is start originally allocated inside MainActivity? I only see it being allocated in your PopUp activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got the answer to my problem but I really don't know why. Good thing I always copy paste my whole code before trying something new.

I think something was wrong with my codes in calling the ActivityforResult because that's where I changed a lot.

Sorry that I was not able to post these two critical codes. I can't even redo for some reason.

But I think it was something like this:

The codes for the PopUp Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUp.class);
        intent.putExtra("route", tag);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and the codes for the SearchCategoryActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchCategory.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

And the solution I made was I changed the onClick for calling the PopUp Activity to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUp.class);
            i.putExtra("route", tag);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Just basically copied the one in calling for SearchCategory and added this line:

```
i.putExtra("route", tag);
```